# Unable to run my Expo app on LAN React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I've updated my expo version to the latest. but unfortunately I don't know why my LAN is not working and expo. I've already tried lots of things example.

1. `expo r -c`
2. Delete node_modules and then `npm install`

but nothing works for me.

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-device": "~1.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~7.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
    "react-native-modal-filter-picker": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.5",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please try to update following in package.json

```
"expo-cli": "3.11.5"
```

Then remove node_modules

```
npm install
```

Comment: Yes absolutely my laptop and mobile are on same network and also it happens after update latest version

Comment: Which expo version you are used ?

Comment: Here is the some latest updates in expo-cli package https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-cli?activeTab=versions

Try to upgrade package version

Comment: please check my package.json file

Comment: I don't know if you need the expo cli for react native taking in mind that in your dependencies you have expo-sdk, which as far as I know, it's the one used for react native. But you should check if it there is a need for using both of them

Comment: The last solution for that is to remove the existing expo-CLI package globally and install a specific version(3.11.3) of this because im my case its works fine, hope its works.

Comment: At the last try to run your code using Android or iOS emulator.